# Docker: Defer startup actions relying on another container?

Tags: mysql, docker, supervisord

I have two types of Docker containers: One with a web application (nginx/php-fpm) and one with a MySQL database. Both are connected through a network. The app container is aware of the DB container, however, the DB doesn’t know if zero, one or more app containers are available. Both types of containers use Supervisord.

The database container has to startup `mysqld`, which can take a few seconds. 
The other container has to perform some startup actions, part of which require database access. As these actions depend on the DB container, I have put a loop at the top of the script, waiting for the DB server to become available:

```
try=0
ok=0

until mysql -h$dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -e "USE $dbname" && ok=1; do
    [ $((++try)) -gt 30 ] && break
    sleep 1
done

if [ $ok -gt 0 ]; then
    # DO STUFF
else
    exit 1
fi
```

While this does work, I see two downsides: First, the script will fail if a DB container is down or takes longer than a certain timeout to start when the app container comes up. Second, the app container won’t know if there are changes on the DB server (e.g. migrations).

While I’m aware of [Supervisord events](http://supervisord.org/events.html), I wonder: How can I notify an arbitrary amount of other containers in the same network of such events?

(NOTE: I’m not restricted to using Supervisord for this, I just feel that this is the most promising approach.)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Compose.

Also you can add an healthcheck to your database container and add a condition for the web server container. Something like this.

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysql_check.sh"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 30s
  retries: 3
```

and

```
depends_on:
  mysql-database:
    condition: service_healthy
```

Compose will wait for the database to be ready before starting the webserver container.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I’m actually using Compose to play with setups. However, I don’t want to depend on it, because I want the containers to be usable with cloud services and other container managers. So I’d prefer a solution running from within the containers, based on discovery and events.

Comment: I see, Docker Compose looks to be compatible with some cloud services (Amazon ECS for example). Orchestrator could also help you (Kubernetes or Swarm) since most of them support Compose.

I dont really use Supervisord so I'm not really going to be able to help you more than that.